# Access VBA update value in array?

Tags: arrays, vba, string, loops

I have an issue with a project I am working on and updating a string within an array when a loop is initiated.

To provide a little context, the code is to amend errors that user's may have made when entering information and to update all the related tables in the one go.

```
Option Compare Database
Dim Var1 As Variant, SQL_select As Variant, SQL_update As Variant, newVar1 As String
Dim j As Integer, rsField As Variant, n As Variant

Public Sub amendCust_control()
  Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, cntRec As Integer, i As Integer, SQL_s As String, SQL_u As String

  For j = 0 To 3
    Var1 = Forms!mm_amendcustomer_temp!Var1
    newVar1 = Forms!mm_amendcustomer_temp!Text50

    assSelArray
    SQL_s = SQL_select(j)
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL_s)

    If rs.EOF Then
      cntRec = 0
    Else
      rs.MoveLast
      cntRec = rs.RecordCount
    End If

    If cntRec > 0 Then
      ReDim n(0 To (cntRec - 1))
      rs.MoveFirst
      For i = 0 To (cntRec - 1)
        n(i) = rs.Fields(rsField(j))
        assignSQLuparray 'populates update field with current value of n(j)
        SQL_u = SQL_update(j)
        Set SQL_update = Nothing
        rs.MoveNext
      Next i
    Else
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
  Next j

  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have then split my **three** string arrays between 2 subs, as below.

```
Private Sub assSelArray()
  SQL_select = Array(("SELECT [Var1] FROM [Customer] WHERE [Var1] = '" & Var1 & "'"), _
    ("SELECT [transNo] FROM [Transactions] WHERE [Var1] = '" & Var1 & "'"), _
    ("SELECT [VAR_O] FROM [Overpayment] WHERE [Var1] = '" & Var1 & "'"), _
    ("SELECT [Access ID] FROM [Audit History] WHERE [Var1] = '" & Var1 & "'"))
  rsField = Array("Var1", "transNo", "VAR_O", "[Access ID]")
End Sub
```

This is the array I am having difficulty with as the values of **n(i)** do not update on each iteration on the code, i.e. when n(i) changes value in the main sub, it does not do so in the array.

```
Private Sub assignSQLuparray()
  SQL_update = Array(("UPDATE [Customer] SET Var1 = '" & newVar1 & "' WHERE Var1 = '" & n(i) & "'"), _
  ("UPDATE [Transactions] SET Var1 = '" & newVar1 & "' WHERE transNo = '" & n(i) & "'"), _
  ("UPDATE [Overpayment] SET Var1 = '" & newVar1 & "' WHERE VAR_O = '" & n(i) & "'"), _
  ("UPDATE [Audit History] SET Var1 = '" & newVar1 & "' WHERE [Access ID] = '" & n(i) & "'"))
End Sub
```

I had hoped someone may be able to help me to essentially 'refresh' the array values before calling them. Help?

*The output was as below:*

```
n(0) = 5 
UPDATE [Audit History] SET Var = newVar1 WHERE [Access ID] = '5'

n(1) = 6 
UPDATE [Audit History] SET Var = newVar1 WHERE [Access ID] = '5'

n(2) = 7 
UPDATE [Audit History] SET Var = newVar1 WHERE [Access ID] = '5'

n(3) = 8 
UPDATE [Audit History] SET Var = newVar1 WHERE [Access ID] = '5'

n(4) = 11 
UPDATE [Audit History] SET Var = newVar1 WHERE [Access ID] = '5'
```

Notice the Access ID does not change as it should to n(0 to 4).

Comment: In `assignSQLuparray` you're referring to `n(i)` even though `n(i)` doesn't change anywhere in that procedure.  The value of "5" is leftover from when `i` was used in a previous procedure.  I'd suggest adding `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always] to help keep variables properly declared and within scope.  If you *want* `i` to reflect changes from another procedure, you'll need to declare it globally instead of locally. See [Understanding Scope](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx) from the amazing Chip Pearson for an overview.

Comment: ...also Microsoft's [Understanding scope and visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility) and [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications).

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion Option Explicit
`Option Explicit`
`Public n As Variant, SQL_update As Variant, i As Integer` and the problem seems solved but I still don't really understand it. :s

Comment: The article seems to suggest that a module level declaration would have sufficed as the it could be read and changed from any sub within the module and the all variables referenced in the loop are contained to the contents of the module so I'm a bit confused.